# Splitting an IEnumerable into two

Tags: c#, linq

I'd like to split a list into two lists, one which can be handled directly, and the other being the remainder, which will be passed down a chain to other handlers.

Input:

- One list of items
- a filtering method to determine which list to include the item in.

Output:

- a "true" list
- a "false" list

Does this already exist? Perhaps a Linq method that I'm not thinking of at the moment? Otherwise, does anyone have a good C# example?

Comment: You use `IEnumerable`, `List` and `Set`, which all have distinct meanings in computer science, for the same thing. Is it correct to assume you meant a sequence `IEnumerable` every time?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Here is one simple method.  Note that `ToLookup` eagerly evaluates the input sequence.

```
List<int> list = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };

var lookup = list.ToLookup(num => num % 2 == 0);

IEnumerable<int> trueList = lookup[true];
IEnumerable<int> falseList = lookup[false];
```

You can use `GroupBy` to get lazy evaluation of the input sequence, but it's not *quite* as pretty:

```
var groups = list.GroupBy(num => num % 2 == 0);

IEnumerable<int> trueList = groups.Where(group => group.Key).FirstOrDefault();
IEnumerable<int> falseList = groups.Where(group => !group.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: (nitpick) `GroupBy` eagerly evaluates the input too.

Comment: @Rawling `GroupBy` evaluates the input as soon as you first start to iterate the `IEnumerable<IGrouping>`.  (i.e. if there was some code after `var groups = ...;` the input would not yet have been iterated.)  `ToLookup` evaluates the input as soon as the method is called.  Essentially the difference would be if you put code that modified the input sequence's results after the call to groupby/lookup and before fetching the `trueList` and `falseList` variables.  If there is nothing in between those (as in my code) then I would just use ToLookup, because it will be cleaner code.

Comment: I'm not sure about your second approach, I mean, you answered to Expro that his approach enumerates the source twice, but with your GroupBy approach you do the same, or not? The questions says that both sequences will be used, so you will do 2 (lazy) enumerations too. Apart from that I agree that in general you have 2 options: 2 live enumerations of the source, or just 1 enumeration + buffering.

Comment: @Wasp Yes, which is why I emphasized the ToLookup approach.  Using GroupBy should really only be used if there's some compelling reason to defer buffering the data; I supposed it's possible to do something that would get the true and false enumerations while only enumerating the source once, if you really, really need the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

After some consideration and some rather rubbish ideas, I've come to the conclusion: don't try to bend LINQ into doing this for you.

Have a simple couple of loops that consume your input sequence, pass each element to the first "handler" that can cope with it, and either ensure your last handler catches everything or at worst return a `List` rather than an `IEnumerable`.

```
public static void Handle(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Action<T> catchAll,
    params Func<T, bool>[] handlers)
{
    foreach (T t in source)
    {
        int i = 0; bool handled = false;
        while (i < handlers.Length && !handled)
            handled = handlers[i++](t);
        if (!handled) catchAll(t);
    }
}

// e.g.
public bool handleP(int input, int p)
{
    if (input % p == 0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is a multiple of {1}", input, p);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}


Handle(
    source,
    i => { Console.WriteLine("{0} has no small prime factor"); },
    i => handleP(i, 2),
    i => handleP(i, 3),
    ...
    );
```

This has the advantage of handling each element in the input order rather than dividing them into groups and losing the ordering prior to whatever you do subsequently.

Comment: Although this seems cool at first, it leaves a bit of a bad taste in my mouth.  I think it has to do with the fact that this would only really be useful because of the side effects it generates, and LINQ queries that generate side effects are...undesirable.  Two possible changes come to mind: eagerly evaluate the sequence, rather than lazily, and/or have a method that takes N "handle" methods (either through `params` or an `IEnumerable<Func<T,bool>>`.

Comment: To be honest, I can totally see where you're coming from.

Comment: Now that I've thought about it, this method is literally just a `Where` that only returns items for which the function returns false instead of true.  (Minus the fact that `Where` eagerly validates the input parameters aren't null.)

Comment: Yup, I noticed that while I was editing (apart from the `null` check)... Really the _ideal_ thing to do here is avoid using LINQ at all...

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Servy's answer, but after the comments going on I thought that this approach could be interesting:

```
static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<TSource> Fork<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> filter,
        Action<TSource> secondary)
    {
        if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("source");
        //...

        return ForkImpl(source, filter, secondary);
    }

    private static IEnumerable<TSource> ForkImpl<TSource>(
        this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, bool> filter,
        Action<TSource> secondary)
    {
        foreach(var e in source)
            if (filter(e))
                yield return e;
            else
                secondary(e);
    }
}
```

this could be used like this:

```
var ints = new [] { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 };

// one possible use of the secondary sequence: accumulation
var acc = new List<int>();

foreach (var i in ints.Fork(x => x % 2 == 0, t => acc.Add(t)))
{
    //...
}

// later on we can process the accumulated secondary sequence
process(acc);
```

Here we do accumulation on the secondary sequence (the "false" values), but live processing of this secondary sequence would be possible too, therefore with just one enumeration of the source.

Answer (score 0):

Using LINQ as much as possible:

```
public IEnumerable<T> Filter(IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, bool> criterium, out IEnumerable<T> remaining)
{
    IEnumerable<T> matching = source.Where(criterium);
    remaining = source.Except(matching);

    return matching;
}
```

Comment: This isn't quite equivalent.  One major problem here is that you're enumerating `source` twice.  Once for the `Where`, and once for the `Except`.  If it's not the same for those two enumerations that would be...bad.  Chills42's code doesn't have that problem.